# Extract only server version from an SQL file

Tags: sql, bash, shell

I am wanting to grep an SQL file to get the following information, however, I am struggling to get it to work - I've tried the following;

```
grep -Poe "-- Server version \K.*" _schemas.sql
```

The line in the SQL dump is

```
    -- MySQL dump 10.13  Distrib 5.1.55, for unknown-linux-gnu (x86_64)
--
-- Host: 10.213.118.88    Database: mysql
-- ------------------------------------------------------
-- Server version   5.1.55
```

The format will not change - I only want to grep the actual numbers of the server version, so in this case, 5.1

```
sqlver=(awk '/Server version/ { split($NF,a,"."); print a[1] "." a[2] }' _schemas.sql)

if [ $sqlver -eq 5.1 ];

then

/opt/migrate/db_import.sh: line 118: [: awk: integer expression expected
```

Comment: This should do the job (print 4th column): `awk '{print $4}' _schemas.sql`

Comment: Sorry this didn't work - I will show you the top lines of the SQL file, I simply need the version from line 5 where the server version is (in main question updated)

Comment: I'm not familiar with mysql version numbering so curious ... why is the expected output `5.1` and not `5.1.55`?

Comment: Please do not expand your question when an answer to your original question has already been given. Thank you.

Comment: `-eq` is used for comparing integers; in this case you probably want to perform a string comparison, eg, `[ "$sqlver" == "5.1" ]`

Comment: `sqlver=(awk ...)` is going to create an array where the first element of the array is the string `awk`; see output from `typeset -p sqlver` to see the structure of the array; what you probably want is `sqlver=$(awk ...)`; getting back to the error message ... `$sqlver` is the same as `${sqlver[0]}` which in this case will be `awk` which in turn is being compared as a numeric (`-eq`) hence the error message: `awk: integer expression expected`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To strip the leftmost spaces, add "*" before `\K`

```
grep -Poe "-- Server version *\K.*" _schemas.sql  #5.1.55
```

To retain only 5.1 in your case, replace `\K.*` with `*\K.{3}` (**What You Want**)

```
grep -Poe "-- Server version *\K.{3}" _schemas.sql  #5.1
```

Where You are not sure whether it's tabs or spaces, use:

```
grep -Poe "-- Server version[ \t]*\K.{3}" _schemas.sql  #5.1
```

**Corresponding sed Versions:**

```
sed -nE "s/-- Server version *(.*)/\1/p" _schemas.sql      #5.1.55

sed -nE "s/-- Server version *(.*)\..*/\1/p" _schemas.sql  #5.1
sed -nE "s/-- Server version[ \t]*(.*)\..*/\1/p" _schemas.sql #5.1
```

Answer (score 0):

One `awk` idea:

```
$ awk '/Server version/ { print $NF }' _schemas.sql
5.1.55
```

If the intent is to display just the first 2 decimal-delimited numbers:

```
$ awk '/Server version/ { split($NF,a,"."); print a[1] "." a[2] }' _schemas.sql
5.1
```

Comment: Thank you, I'm then trying to tie this into an if statement and I get the above error (see above)

Answer (score 0):

The following gives you the first two components of the version.

*-- Server version* and the version string can be separated by any number of spaces or tabs.

```
sed -ne "s/^-- Server version[ \t]*\([0-9]\{1,\}\.[0-9]\{1,\}\)\..*$/\1/p" < _schemas.sql
```